# Check if node has actions being processed?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm executing the SKAction rotateToAngle on one method. On another method I want to know in whether the action is still being executed or if it has ended.

I could  save the time the action started in a property and check it however I was wondering whether there is an easier method.

```
private func rotate(motionManager: CMMotionManager, gravity: CGVector) {
    let rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI * 5), duration: 5.0, shortestUnitArc: true)
    self.runAction(rotate)
}
private func actionRunning() --> Bool {

}
```

I tried using self.hasActions() but it always return true. Any ideas on how to do this on Swift?

Comment: sequence with a runblock action at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the withKey parameter when using runAction.  Then do a actionForKey: method to determine if it still exists.

In Objective-C it looks like this:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:0.1] withKey:@"waitTimer"];
[self actionForKey:@"waitTimer"];
```

I'm not familiar with Swift, but the Apple Docs do show it supported for the Swift Language as well.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:withKey:

```
func runAction(_ action: SKAction!,
   withKey key: String!)
```